# AKS with LetsEncrypt and multiple certs for different containers

Tags: azure, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks, azure-application-gateway, ingress-controller

I'm looking for any working samples of applying different certificates on AKS with Application Gateway as Ingress Controller.
I have Key Vault with a certificate that is used imported in ApGw/Ingress as **sitecomcert** and here is Ingress manifest:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: site-agic-ig
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: azure/application-gateway
    appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/appgw-ssl-certificate: sitecomcert
    appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
    appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/request-timeout: "180"
    appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/cookie-based-affinity: "true"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: "site.com"
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: site-svc
            port:
              number: 80
```

...

Everything works perfect here.
Now I have a second certificate in Key Vault for **site2.com** and this cert is already imported in Ap Gw as **site2comcert** and I have container that should serve requests coming to site2.com which point to Ap Gw Public IP.
So I'm about to add

```
- host: "site2.com"   <--- How can I attach **site2comcert** cert? 
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: site2-svc
            port:
              number: 80
```

but with this setup I receive Untrusted Connection warning in browser because **sitecomcert** is used. How to configure ApGw / Ingress in a way that allows to use **site2comcert** for site2.com host specified above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have multiple ingress resource definitions (snipped for brevity):

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: site-agic-ig
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: azure/application-gateway
    appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/appgw-ssl-certificate: sitecomcert
spec:
  rules:
  - host: "site.com"
```

and

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: site-agic-ig-site2
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: azure/application-gateway
    appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/appgw-ssl-certificate: site2comcert
spec:
  rules:
  - host: "site2.com"
```